# Savage beast plugin for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to update the Savage Beast plugin for my rails 3.0.1
application's forum from rails 2.3.8, Is it available for Rails 3.0.1
version or is there any plugin patch is available to update from rails
2.3.8 to Rails 3.0.1 ?

Thanks in Advance,
Jak.

Answer (score 1):

I've ported Altered Beast to Rails 3. Grab it here: https://github.com/stiff/altered_beast

Any feedback and testing is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Stiff,

 i ll check that one, But i modified the rails 2 savage_beast plugin by moving all file from plugin folder to main application folder and configured routing for the same and fixed the forum for rails 3. It is working fine for me.

 Anyway i ll also check this plugin,


Thanks,
Arun